# Javascript recursive function - call to asynchronous function at the leave level

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

In the following program, when `recurse(prog)` is initially called (line 64), it recursively digs into the expressions `exp` described in `prog` (line 1), switching between the case where exp.type = A, B or C.

At the bottom most level of the recursive call (when case("C")), I am calling `verySlowMan(exp.value)` that looks up a list of `collections` to check whether a collection with the name of exp.value exists or not.

If yes, the collection is returned

If no, a new `Error`is return

The problem is that `verySlowMan()` take his time to retrieve a collection.

*For simplicity, I made a simple `if else` condition, but `verySlowMan` will ultimately make an XHR request. So it is unpredictably slow*

**The question is the following** :

**How to propagate the return value of verySlowMan all the way up the recursive call to get a nice list of collections as a result of calling recurse(prog) ?**

Currently, for understandable reasons, I get [ null, [ null, null ], null ]. But I have really no clue about how to solve it.

I tried to return a deferred.promises from `verySlowMan`, but in this case I think recurse() should also return a new promise for each recursive call.

(1) I'm not sure about how to make this properly

(2) I doubt it's the best way

NB : The amount of items in `prog`, `collections` and the cases in recurse() can potentially become very long.

Here is the program :

```
var prog = {
  type : "A", value : [
    { type : "B", value : "C1" },
    { type : "B", value : [
      { type : "C", value : "C2" },
      { type : "C", value : "end" }
    ]},
    { type : "B", value : "C3" }
  ]
}

var collections = [
  { name : "C1", data : ["item1", "item2", "item3"]},
  { name : "C2", data : ["item1", "item2", "item3"]}
]

function verySlowMan( collectionToFind ){

  collections.forEach(function(collection){

    if ( collection.name === collectionToFind ) {
      return collection;
    }else{
      return new Error("No Collection");
    }
  });

  return null;
}

function recurse(exp){

  switch(exp.type){
    case("A"):
      var As = [];
      exp.value.forEach( function(B){
        As.push ( recurse(B) );
      } );
      return As;
      break;

    case("B"):
      var Bs = [];
      if (typeof(exp.value) === 'string') {
        return verySlowMan( exp.value );

      } else {
        exp.value.forEach( function(C){
          Bs.push ( recurse(C) );
        } );
        return Bs;
      }
      break;

    case("C"):
      return verySlowMan( exp.value );
      break;

    default:
      throw new Error('wrong type');
  }
}

console.log( recurse(prog) ); // -> [ null, [ null, null ], null ]
```

Comment: what expected output for your sample? seems like always should `throw new Error`

Comment: also when you so return inside `forEach` callback - it not return from function where `forEach` run

Comment: you would have to use callbacks and the whole recursion function will return the result in callbacks, if this is ok for your use case

Comment: In your example verySlowMan is not asynchronous. That makes your code confusing. Also, do you want to work with normal callbacks or with promises? You need to write all loops and recursive function calls in an asynchronous style if those internally also call asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with promises.

```
function verySlowMan( collectionToFind ) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
        if ( collections[i].name === collectionToFind ) {
          resolve(collections[i]);
          return;
        }
      }
      reject(new Error("No Collection"));
    }, 100);
  });
}

function recurse(exp){
  function errorHandler(err) {
    if(err.message === "No Collection") return null;
    else throw err;
  };
  switch(exp.type){
    case("A"):
      return Promise.all(exp.value.map(recurse));
    case("B"):
      if (typeof(exp.value) === 'string') {
        return verySlowMan(exp.value).catch(errorHandler);
      } else {
        return Promise.all(exp.value.map(recurse));
      }
    case("C"):
      return verySlowMan( exp.value ).catch(errorHandler);

    default:
      return Promise.reject(new Error('wrong type'));
  }
}

recurse(prog).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.stack);
});
```

Comment: As I understand, you are using Promise from ES6. Could I do the same with Q ?

Comment: Ok, with Q it's pretty much the same. 
but instead of
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
I used
  return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject)

Thanks a lot for the help